# Broken LaTeX rendering of markdown differences

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, diff, mathjax

The LaTeX renderer interacts badly with markdown differences. Since markdown differences are raw source-code, the LaTeX renderer should ignore it.

For example https://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1633 renders broken markdown on the right.

Screenshot (Opera 12.02):
[image: Screenshot]

It only happens when I'm logged into crypto.SE, which explains why it only occurred in Opera and not FF for me. Clearing cookies fixed it, until I logged in again.

Comment: It doesn't render Markdown when viewing the "markdown diffs"option for me... Just plain source-code text. Are you sure you selected the correct option? "rendered output diffs" is always selected by default.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It doesn't render markdown, but MathJax attempts to render latex output. | Seems to be Opera specific, can't reproduce with FF.

Comment: I've tried in FF, Chrome, and Opera. Can't reproduce in any. I tried in IE, but couldn't get the review item to load (it just sticks on the "loading item" part).

Comment: Only occurs while I'm logged into crypto.SE.

Comment: This seems to be a regression of [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121786/when-show-markdown-source-diffs-side-by-side-option-is-used-mathjax-will-try)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks.

The reason that you only saw this when logged in, and that not everybody saw it, is that MathJax only touches visible items. But the default diff view is the rendered diff, and thus – unless you're logged in *and* your preference is set to the source diff – the source diff is hidden when MathJax runs.