# MathJax is (inappropriately) parsed in Markdown diffs

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, diff

I just noticed that [this diff](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/68537/revisions) (select "side-by-side markdown" mode if it's not already selected) is showing MathJax where it doesn't belong:

[image: Screenshow of inappropriate MathJax in Markdown diff]

(MathJax right-click menu included to show that those italics are indeed MathJax.)

Chrome's DOM inspector shows that the diff in fact does have a parent element with the class name `markdown-diff tex2jax_ignore`, which *should* cause MathJax to ignore its contents.  Clearly, however, this is broken somehow.  I suspect either that some JS code is calling [`MathJax.Hub.Typeset`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.0/typeset.html) directly on one of the inner elements, or else that the MathJax config specifying the class names to ignore is somehow broken (which, at a glance, it doesn't seem to be).

Either way, this is clearly a bug, and should be fixed.

---

Ps. This seems to be a regression of [When "show markdown source diffs side by side" option is used, MathJax will try to interpret $ signs in markdown source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121786/when-show-markdown-source-diffs-side-by-side-option-is-used-mathjax-will-try) and [Broken LaTeX rendering of markdown differences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152768/broken-latex-rendering-of-markdown-differences), both of which have been marked as fixed back in 2012.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted. I can reproduce this in both Edge and Chrome. In my opinion, Markdown view should *only* consist of Markdown, and shouldn't be parsed in any way. Is it because others can't reproduce this issue?

Comment: This appears to be a timing issue.  We are adding the `tex2jax_ignore` class to markdown diffs in JavaScript that may or may not execute before MathJax.  For me, it renders incorrectly on Safari < 10% of the time but 100% of the time in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed.

There was a race condition where we were marking adding the class `tex2jax_ignore` to elements with the class `markdown-diff` but sometimes only after MathJax had traversed the DOM.  Since we only use `markdown-diff` a couple places and they all should be ignoring MathJax, I added `tex2jax_ignore` to the page source rather than doing it in JavaScript.

Comment: I think https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326711/200582 may be caused by the fix, since I see a MathJax-related error in the console?